# Using Hapi h2o2 with nginx ('worker_connections are not enough' error)

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, hapi.js

I have an API server developed with Hapi that proxies POST requests on specific endpoints to a different server (also written with Hapi) that handles long running async jobs.
Requests to: 
 `http://my-api-staging.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/v1/importer/items`
 are proxied to: 
 `http://my-services-staging.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/v1/importer/items`
preserving all HTTP headers of the original request.

The server that receives the proxied request is also written with Hapi and is used to process long running jobs.
On the API server, Hapi h2o2 plugin handles the request proxying. The code for a proxied route looks like this:

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/importer/items',
    config: {
      payload: {
        parse: false
      },
      handler: {
          proxy: {
            passThrough: true,
            xforward: true,
            host: SERVICES_HOST,
            port: SERVICES_PORT,
            protocol: SERVICES_PROTOCOL,
            onResponse: function(err, res, request, reply, settings, ttl) {
              var response = (err) ? err : res;

              return reply(response);
            }
          }
        }
     }
}
```

When I run both servers on `localhost` (binding API Server and Job Server on different ports), everything works fine.

I've set up both servers on different Microsoft Azure VMs, binding them on port 3000 with nginx in front acting as reverse proxy.
My nginx config look like this (same on both servers, just `server_name` changes):

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name my-api-staging.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;


   location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

Requests are handled correctly by nginx with other routes not involving proxying the request on a different remote machine.
Problems start when I send a request through Postman or with curl on the VM on some endpoint that involves remote proxying:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Bearer: foobar' 
            -H 'Authorization: token somerandomstring' 
            -H "Content-type: application/json"      
     'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/importer/items'
```

nginx hangs for some seconds, sending back a 500 Internal Server Error. 
Tailing `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, 
client: 127.0.0.1, 
server: my-api-staging.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com, 
request: "POST /api/v1/importer/items HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/importer/items", 
host: "my-api-staging.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"
```

Setting `worker_connections 20000;` does not solve the problem, yielding 400 Bad Request.
Tailing `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
```

I guess there is some kind of loop going on and nginx cannot correctly process the multiple redirections with the configuration I have supplied.

I want to be able to process this kind of request flow:

```
(Request) -> nginx:80 -> API server:3000 -> nginx:80 -> Jobs server:3000
                                        h2o2
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`reply.proxy(options) API`](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2#replyproxyoptions) apparently solved the problem out of the box, with no change made on the nginx config. 
I also removed the `xforward` options which defaults to `false` when not present.

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/importer/items',
    config: {
      payload: {
        parse: false
      },
      handler: function(request, reply) {
      return reply.proxy({
        host: SERVICES_HOST,
        port: SERVICES_PORT,
        protocol: SERVICES_PROTOCOL,
        passThrough: true,
        onResponse: function(err, res, request, reply, settings, ttl) {
          var response = (err) ? err : res;

          return reply(response);
        }
      });
    }
}
```